# child mesh jumps and scales when reparenting

Tags: parent

I have to first un-parent (clear parent) and then again re-parent sub-objects otherwise they get scaled and moved.   Is there a sensible use for this unexpected reaction or something I'm missing when I want to change the parent hierarchy of several objects?
I will attach an example file.

[image: re-parented sub-objects]

[image: Outliner view]

[image]

Comment: When un-parent (Alt+P) choose "Clear and keep Transformation"

Comment: Aside from what @vklidu suggested, it is usually much simpler (to me anyway) to use empties as controller objects rather than to use object/ sub-object hierarchies in most scenes.

Comment: "Clear and keep Transformation" often doesn't work.  The object can still become completely resized.